# Javascript field value length

Tags: javascript, string

I'm doing something like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('cardNumber').value);
```

And it alerts cardNumber value. But I need in its length:

```
alert(document.getElementById('cardNumber').value.lenght);
```

> undefined

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the word is spelled 'length'.

Comment: :D I have to sleep now. Thanks.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?